# How to set the checked status of an asp.net user control'checkbox from one to another

Tags: asp.net

I am having a asp.net web page on which I am loading a single usercontrol (UC) ten times. The first user control will be used to gather data about the ​main employee and the rest about his dependent. There will be "next" and "Previous" navigation button to move from one UC to another. I have couple of DevExpress check boxes on the UC. If the user checks any of them on the first page and then clicks the "next" button to navigate to the next UC, I want the checkboxes in the dependent UC also checked. I tried to do that in the page load event of the dependent controls in code behind. The code is given below. But it doesn't work. Looks like that I have to use javascript to do it. Please let me know how to do it.

codebehind:

```
dependentCheckbox.checked = mainEmployeeCheckbox.checked;
```

Thanks​

Comment: Are you dynamically loading the user controls into the UI?

Comment: In the html side i am configuring these 10 controls

Comment: What do you mean by "configuring"?  You mean changing values?  Can you post your markup?  it's hard to tell otherwise.